# opening drawer by pressing on bottom tab not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to `toggleDrawer` on `TabPress` in `BottomTab`, but when I press on tab I get the following error `navigation.toggleDrwer() is not a function`.

This is my code:

```
export default function BottomTab() {


    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerTab} style={styles} listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
                    tabPress: e => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        navigation.toggleDrawer()
                    },
                })} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have manage to find the answer. So you actually have to use dispatch.

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerTab} style={styles} listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
                    tabPress: e => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())
                    },
                })} />
```